# Using PUSH {lr} and POP {pc} to return from main/_start function in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to understand how to properly exit from a basic program in ARM and I've seen a lot of code which use `PUSH {lr}` to save the return address of the calling function (provided that the caller used `BL` to save the return address in `lr`) to then later retrieve it and branch to the return address using `POP {pc}`. I have no issues getting this to work with subroutines inside a main/_start function since the `lr` register is changed by `BL` in those cases but using the code below the value pushed onto the stack will simply be 0x0, causing an error on return.

```
    .text
    .global main

    main:
            PUSH {lr}  
            MOV r0, #42 
            POP {pc}
    .end
```

I've ran code with a lot more external things which use this exact method to return from the main function with out a `Segmentation Fault` but when I try to run this base program using the gdb debugger its obvious that `lr` stays at zero in the first line of main and thus gives an error on return. In essence my question is how to acquire the correct value for `lr` when pushing it onto the stack in the main function.

I used

```
     $ as -g ex.s -o ex && ld -e main ex.o -o ex
```

to compile the executable.

EDIT : I found out that using

```
     $ gcc ex.o -o ex
```

to link the program partially answered my question, looking at the output of gdb I found that `gcc` seems to initialise `lr` with a correct value making the example program exit normally. I would however still like to know if there is a method of attaining this address when using `ld` as I did before.

Comment: If you link with `ld -e main` you tell the linker that `main` is your entry point, i.e. that's where the OS starts your program.  There is nothing to return to from an entry point, which is why your program crashes.  If you link through the C compiler, a stub is linked in that calls your `main` function.  Returning from `main` works in this case and the stub calls `exit` for you to exit the program if you return from `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ELF entry point isn't a *function*, there is no user-space caller to return to, and there's no return address anywhere.  All you get is the stack pointer pointing to `argc` and then the `argv[]` array (not a pointer to it), then `env[]`.

You need to make a `sys_exit` system call (like the libc `_exit(2)` function).

---

Linking with `ld -e main ex.o -o ex` makes a static executable with `main` as the ELF entry point.  Changing the name from the default `_start` does nothing to help you, and is just confusing for everyone.  I don't recommend it.